# where am I being limited?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have this piece of code in my views.py for a django app:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    tablestring = tablestring + "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "</td><td>" + + str(row[3]) + "</td></tr>"
```

This works fine when I load the page but if I change the range to (0,20) or anything higher, I just get a blank page. My question is: what is causing this limitation? Is it something with python or django or with the host (pythonanywhere)?

Also, I'm just starting with django and I understand this may not be the best code. If you have any suggestions to make it neater or more efficient they would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help

Edit: here is my query:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT title, movie_url, movie_id, cScore  FROM movies""")
```

Comment: Please show your SQL query. Do you have a reason to use cursor over django ORM?

Comment: I've added the query. I'm not familiar with django ORM. What does it do?

Comment: What http status are you getting when the page is returned blank?

Comment: The page is still loading. If I add other stuff to the html file it will display, but the content from views.py will not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should really use [django orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) and write those table markups in a [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/), follow this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) to get the basic concepts

Comment: I just quickly scanned that tutorial. Is there a way to make models using the data I currently have in a mysql db?

Comment: The model does not describe the data contained in the database, only the table schemas. So yes, you should have no problem.

Comment: That looks like it will help. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that there are less than 20 rows, so once you run out of them `row` will be None and your attempt to index it will throw an exception.

As for improving the code:

Like Yossi suggested, you should probably go with an ORM. An ORM (Object Relational Mapper) lets you access a database in a more object-oriented way, which can make for cleaner code as well as avoid bugs related to argument escaping (on the other hand, it may not be ideal if you want to create really complex queries, for that SQL is still the best IMHO).

I also agree with Guy in that you should using a template system instead of concatenating HTML strings.